# How to use OpenNLP models in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, opennlp

I try to use OpenNLP models in NetBeans. First I downloaded `.bin` files but they are in `.zip` format. Then I put them in my project directory where `build.xml` file exists. I don't know why model files are not recognized?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. 
I just changed .zip extensions to .bin and it worked